# How to SSH tunnel and connect to a database using IntelliJ and JDBC?

Tags: java, jdbc, intellij-idea, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I'm having issues connecting to a database hosted on a server using IntelliJ and JDBC. With the command line, the command:

```
ssh username@server -L 11100:ct1:28017 -N
```

creates a tunnel successfully and the command:

```
psql db_name -h localhost -p 11100 db_username
```

connects to the database fine and allows me to use it. How would this be translated correctly into the IntelliJ Data Sources and the SSH tunnel tools?

At the moment, for the SSH tunnel settings I have:

Proxy Host: server

Port: 22

Proxy user: username

For the general tab I have:

host: localhost

port: 28017

database: db_name

user: db_username

The connection returns successfully after testing the connection. Inside my program I have:

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:28017/db_name", user, password);
```

The URL parameter is the one generated by IntelliJ. This however gives me an error "Connection to localhost:28017 refused."

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is the port `28017` opened?

Comment: @Andremoniy On the server, yes it's open.

Comment: It looks like you locally use port 11100 for the SSH tunnel, that is the port number you need to specify in your connection string (just like you do in `psql db_name -h localhost -p 11100 db_username`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you connect to SSH server from a java client like SSHJ (https://github.com/hierynomus/sshj) ?

The URL on your DriverManager seems wrong: try port 11100 instead.

Comment: That seemed to have worked. I still ended up using Jsch library and its port forwarding.

Answer (score 12):

Here's my setup via intellij if anyone is looking for simple solution without external libraries.

1. Open Database view (View -> Tool Windows -> Database).
2. Add new DataSource (right-click, New -> Data Source ->
   Postgres/Mysql). **In host, use 127.0.0.1 (not localhost, sometimes
   localhost is not properly resolved).**
3. Fill in rest of the fields as configured on your remote host.

[image]

Now click on SSH/SSL tab and configure ssl tunnel:

[image]

Comment: You can browse the database but how would you connect to this from your application ?

Comment: @MohitSingh that depends on the application and its configuration - whether it's spring boot, node or something else. You won't get one sentence answer.

Comment: What I meant was does this make the DB accessible on some port ? The op's question `ssh username@server -L 11100:ct1:28017 -N` exposes the database on port 11100 which wasn't accessible before due to some VPC. But with this, it can be connected to from application directly irrespective of application stack or configuration.

Comment: This worked for me in intellij

Comment: Any idea how this would work for a file-based database and not a listening server database? I was under the impression intellij was using something like sshfs and not necessarily port forwarding, considering I was using sqlite and in that mindset. I ended up just using sshfs anyway. Your answer helped me see the inteded use though, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the error is `Exhausted available authentication methods` ❶, make sure that the passphrase ❷ is provided if required. This is easy to forget because the passphrase is often supplied automatically by the OS keyring manager, which makes it seem like the key does not have one.

The credentials in ❸ are for Postgres. These will not work with peer authentication. In my case, I needed this in `pg_hba.conf`:

```
hostnossl  all  rdahl  127.0.0.1/32  md5
```

The proxy host and user in ❹ are for the ssh server as seen from the client.

The docs from JetBrains are odd and left me in doubt if this is just using an existing SSH tunnel, or if it creates one. It **creates** one.

The `Test Connection` buttons in the two dialogs both trigger the same test.

[image: SSH credentials dialog]
[image: Data sources general]
[image: Data sources SSH]

Comment: i have successfully tunned the db but not sure how to give this URL in the data source. 
I am running a spring boot application and need to give Datasource URL in application.yaml , any leads how can we do that?

Comment: For Postgres tunneled to localhost with default port, my guess is `jdbc:postgresql:database`. Where `database` is the name of your database. More info: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/80/connect.html.